# solr suggester - splitting on apostrophe

Tags: solr

I've been trying to add a suggester feature to my site that uses Apache Solr for searching. For the most part, everything works as I'd expect. I run into trouble when trying to search words with apostrophes (ex. don't, weren't, isn't, etc).

For some reason the suggester is splitting the word on the apostrophe and then returning a collation result. For example, "don't y" returns "don't'the you"; so it's providing a collation where "don"->"don't", "t"->"the", and "y"->"you".

I've used the analyzer and it doesn't look like the tokenizers/filters are splitting on the apostrophe, so I'm not sure why this is happening. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

schema.xml:

```
<fieldType name="textSpell" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" omitNorms="true">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="naughtywords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="naughtywords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

solrconfig.xml:

```
<searchComponent class="solr.SpellCheckComponent" name="suggest">
  <lst name="spellchecker">
    <str name="name">suggest</str>
    <str name="classname">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.Suggester</str>
    <str name="lookupImpl">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.tst.TSTLookupFactory</str>
    <str name="field">spellCheckContent</str>
    <float name="threshold">0.001</float>
    <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
  </lst>
</searchComponent>
<requestHandler class="org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler" name="/suggest">
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="spellcheck">true</str>
    <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">suggest</str>
    <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">true</str>
    <str name="spellcheck.count">5</str>
    <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
    <str name="spellcheck.maxCollations">5</str>
    <str name="spellcheck.collateExtendedResults">true</str>
    <str name="spellcheck.maxCollationTries">10</str>
    <str name="df">spellCheckContent</str>
  </lst>
  <arr name="components">
    <str>suggest</str>
    <str>query</str>
  </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

suggester results:

```
"spellcheck": {
"suggestions": [
  "don",
  {
    "numFound": 4,
    "startOffset": 0,
    "endOffset": 3,
    "suggestion": [
      "don't",
      "don’t",
      "done",
      "donating"
    ]
  },
  "t",
  {
    "numFound": 5,
    "startOffset": 4,
    "endOffset": 5,
    "suggestion": [
      "the",
      "to",
      "this",
      "talk",
      "that"
    ]
  },
  "y",
  {
    "numFound": 4,
    "startOffset": 6,
    "endOffset": 7,
    "suggestion": [
      "you",
      "your",
      "years",
      "year",
    ]
  }
}
```